# asserts are not being executed with pub serve

Tags: dart

the code below does not get executed:

```
assert((){ print('hi'); });
```

Terminal log:

```
pub serve
Loading source assets... 
Loading angular2 and dart_to_js_script_rewriter transformers... 
Serving checkoutFrontEduzz web on http://localhost:8080
Build completed successfully
[web] GET Served 11 cached assets.
[web] GET Served 634 cached assets.
[web] GET Served 2 cached assets.
[web] GET assets/css/hotsite.component.css.map → (cached) checkoutFrontEduzz|web/assets/css/hotsite.component.css.map
```

my pubspec:

```
transformers:
- angular2:
    platform_directives:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES'
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#FORM_DIRECTIVES'
    platform_pipes:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES'
    entry_points: web/main.dart
    resolved_identifiers:
        BrowserClient: 'package:http/browser_client.dart'
        Client: 'package:http/http.dart'
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```

Teste with chrome and dartium.

Comment: What does your `$dart2js` transformer section in `pubspec.yaml` look like? Did you test with Dartium or with Chrome or some other non-Dartium browser?

Comment: edited with the info you asked

Comment: I Dartium I get `Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null`, I haven't tried with another browser, but AFAIK `pub serve` emits production JS when loaded by Chrome, Firefox, ... .

Comment: How do you start Dartium?

Comment: I have copied the .app into the Applications folder (OSX) and then regularly start with command + space and type it's name. It also did not get executed in regular chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get assertion errors in Dartium you need to ensure it runs with checked mode enabled

```
DART_FLAGS='--checked' path/chrome
```

See also https://webdev.dartlang.org/tools/dartium

`pub serve` produces production output, because debug output runs too slow as far as I remember, therefore it's expected behavior that you don't get the error in Chrome. You need to run `pub build --mode="debug"` and load the output in Chrome to get the error.

Comment: It also does not get executed within Chrome. I don't know if it is important, but when I use webStorm and try to execute it from there, webStorm tries to load a different html file. My is index.html and it tries to load the project name .html. Weird

Comment: I mentioned it in a comment below your question already. `pub serve` produces production JS output because debug mode JS is too slow. See my updated answer.

Comment: but this changed, right? I use to test assert fails with pub serve. Maybe something changed in the project. Gonna dig it.

Comment: What is "this" in "this changed"? You need to run Dartium in checked mode, there was no change recently AFAIK (could be that longer ago it was the default but I don't know because I always run it from an IDE and there checked just was always the default). Also `pub serve` emitting production mode JS didn't change, at least not within the last year or so.